# How prove this matrix equation $AXB=C$ has a solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

**Qustion:**

if  Matrix equation $AY = C$ and $ZB = C$  has solution,

show that:

the equation of $AXB= C$ has  solution

This problem is from this PDF(page 3) problem     2 :http://wenku.baidu.com/view/d6625d1cff00bed5b9f31dba.html

My idea:we have
$$\left(A\bigotimes I\right)\overline{Y}=\overline{C}$$
$$\left(I\bigotimes B^T\right)\overline{Z}=\overline{C}$$
we only prove
$$\left(A\bigotimes B^T\right)\overline{X}=\overline{C}$$ has solution.

since
$$\left(A\bigotimes  I\right)\left(I\bigotimes B^T\right)=A\bigotimes  B^T$$
then ony prove follow
$$I_{m}\left(A\bigotimes  I\right)\bigcap I_{m}\left(I\bigotimes  B^T\right)\subset I_{m}\left(A\bigotimes B^T\right)$$
My idea is wrong? If is true,and follow How works? Thank you

and maybe have other methods.Thank you very much!

Comment: For matrices $A$, $B$, it is not always true that $Im(A)\cap Im(B)\subset Im(AB)$. So, I wouldn't try this approach.

Comment: Why $Im(A)\bigcap Im(B)\subset Im(AB)$ this is not always true?

Comment: Consider nilpotent matrix $A$. In particular, if $A$ is a nonzero matrix with $A^2=0$, then $Im(A)=Im(B)\neq (0)$, but $Im(A^2)=Im(0)=(0)$.

Comment: This exercise shows that if $im(C)\subset im(A)$ and $\ker(B)\subset\ker(C)$, then the equation $AXB=C$ has at least one solution. Moreover, the converse is obviously true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will assume that your matrices are over a regular ring (maybe even over a field). Then each of these is regular. By this I mean for $A$ there is matrix $A^-$ such that $AA^-A=A$.

Then the first two equations you have imply that

$AA^-C=C$ and

$CB^-B=C$.

Now you may like to guess what a solution of $AXB=C$ may be. If not see bellow.

Answer $X=A^- CB^-$.

Comment: $CB^{-}B=C$ a typo.