# When does the matrix equation $AXB = C$ have a solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-equations

> When is the matrix equation $$AXB = C$$ solvable for $X$? Assume non-square matrices $A$, $B$, $C$ and $X$ with compatible dimensions.

I need the answer in terms of relations between their rank/nullity/range spaces/null spaces etc.

Comment: See this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/585419/how-prove-this-matrix-equation-axb-c-has-a-solution?rq=1 , comments and answer.

Comment: @i707107: Thanks! I've understood that. But that just implies that the condition of solvability is that the other two matrix equations need to be solvable. Is that it? Do we need more conditions for the solution X to exist?

Comment: As @loup blanc's comment to the question in the link, we need $im(C)\subseteq im(A)$ and $ker(B)\subseteq ker(C)$.

Comment: @i707107: I see. Those two are basically solvability conditions for the other two equations. Ya it makes sense. If those two are solvable separately, the combined equation will have a solution too. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 2):

We have the matrix equation in $\mathrm X \in \mathbb R^{n \times p}$

$$\mathrm A \mathrm X \mathrm B = \mathrm C$$

where $\mathrm A \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$, $\mathrm B \in \mathbb R^{p \times q}$ and $\mathrm C \in \mathbb R^{m \times q}$ are given.

Left-multiplying by $\mathrm A^T$ and right-multiplying by $\mathrm B^T$, we obtain

$$\mathrm A^T \mathrm A \mathrm X \mathrm B \mathrm B^T = \mathrm A^T \mathrm C \mathrm B^T$$

If $\mathrm A$ has **full column rank** and $\mathrm B$ has **full row rank**, then $\mathrm A^T \mathrm A$ and $\mathrm B \mathrm B^T$ are invertible. Hence,

$$\hat{\mathrm X} := (\mathrm A^T \mathrm A)^{-1} \mathrm A^T \mathrm C \mathrm B^T (\mathrm B \mathrm B^T)^{-1}$$

is a candidate solution. Left-multiplying $\hat{\mathrm X}$ by $\mathrm A$ and right-multiplying it by $\mathrm B$, we obtain

$$\mathrm A \hat{\mathrm X} \mathrm B = \underbrace{\mathrm A (\mathrm A^T \mathrm A)^{-1} \mathrm A^T}_{=: \mathrm P_{\mathrm A}} \mathrm C \underbrace{\mathrm B^T (\mathrm B \mathrm B^T)^{-1} \mathrm B}_{=: \mathrm P_{\mathrm B^T}} = \mathrm P_{\mathrm A} \mathrm C \mathrm P_{\mathrm B^T}$$

where $\mathrm P_{\mathrm A}$ and $\mathrm P_{\mathrm B^T}$ are the projection matrices that project onto the column space of $\mathrm A$ and the row space of $\mathrm B$, respectively. If

$$\mbox{Im} (\mathrm C) \subseteq \mbox{Im} (\mathrm A) \qquad \qquad \qquad \mbox{Im} (\mathrm C^T) \subseteq \mbox{Im} (\mathrm B^T)$$

then

$$\mathrm P_{\mathrm A} \mathrm C \mathrm P_{\mathrm B^T} = \mathrm C$$

and the candidate solution $\hat{\mathrm X}$ is indeed a solution to the matrix equation $\mathrm A \mathrm X \mathrm B = \mathrm C$.

Comment: Thanks! But what if the full row and full column rank assumptions are not made? Is there a general case?

Comment: The general case also is covered by $im (C)\subseteq im (A)$ and $im (C^T) \subseteq im (B^T)$. Note that $im (C^T) \subseteq im (B^T)$ is also equivalent to $ker (B)\subseteq ker (C)$.

Comment: This works as long as you have matrices over a von Neumann regular ring, which of course includes fields. See Any's answer in the link.